# Windows: Call a process for a user

Tags: c, winapi

i have written a windows service `Foo_Updater.exe` as an updater for my program `Foo.exe`. This service starts with booting and has admin privilegues. `Foo.exe` has a GUI and a Trayicon. That's the situation.

The last thing before finishing the update process. `Foo_Updater.exe` will run the new (updated) version of `Foo.exe` - successfully. But there is one problem: `Foo.exe` runs for the admin-user (`SYSTEM`) and not as the local logged in user (I see that in the TaskManager). The real problem is that the trayicon is not visible.

So my question: Can I run `Foo.exe` as local process (only knowing the username)?
I heard about functions like `CreateProcessAsUser()`, but they depends on a structure given per `LogonUser()` and this function has an argument `password`. I don't know the password, of course.

Any ideas?

EDIT: A important thing to say is: The program location is `C:\Program Files (x86)\Foo\`. Thus, normal programs do not have writing permissions. Thats the reason to write a service which have that privilegues. I also can not start the service or the updater from the normal running program `Foo.exe` 'cause that so called program do have the same permissions as `Foo.exe` and can not write into `C:\Program Files (x86)\Foo\`.

Comment: Do you have any objections to sending `Foo.exe` a message asking it to restart itself?

Comment: @dsolimano: I have to close the program to update it (you can not modify the files of running programs). When an update is available: 1. close program; 2. update; 3. start program; 4. be happy

Comment: You might find this useful - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8984460/c-sharp-on-windows-updating-a-program-while-its-still-running

Comment: @dsolimano Thats a tip, but my update process is self-made so no MSI is used. I download and change files by myself.

Comment: Right, the MSIness of the installation process is an implementation detail of that answer, you can do the same thing.  The essential bit is download to a temporary installation, send a message to foo.exe to run the installer from the temp location with a flag to restart foo.exe.

Comment: @dsolimano please see my edit of the question

Comment: i wrote a service like `psexec` to run applications on the users level ... `CreateProcessAsUser()` can also be called with the user that is currently logged in and you can query that user information struct. maybe this will help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8574716/create-process-as-user

Comment: @Zaiborg Thanks i will try and post my experience here.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's going to be difficult to get the service, running in session 0, to start a process on the current interactive desktop, in a different session. I would not attempt to do that. Following that route will lead to pain.

The obvious alternative is to get the process that runs on the interactive desktop to start the updated program. The sequence of events goes like this:

1. The service notices that there is an update to download, downloads that update.
2. When the service is ready to update it communicates with any running instances of the program on interactive desktops.
3. If all the running instances agree to the update they start another process, that runs silently in the background, hidden from view. Let's call this other process the update watcher.
4. Once the main process has started the update watcher, it terminates.
5. Now that the main process has terminated, the updater can install the update.
6. Once the update has been installed, the service communicates with the update watcher to inform it that the update is complete.
7. The update watcher starts the updated program and terminates itself.

You might even decide to make the update watcher show some UI to report progress on the update.

Comment: That's a good point. But, logically, the updater can modify *all* components even the update watcher (if it has a bug).

Comment: The update watcher can perfectly well be downloaded by your service.

Answer (score 0):

I think that the bet way to do it is to have 1 exe running as service to run all privileged actions and 1 exe running at any user login (**all users/start menu/start** or something like that will do it for you) for the tray icon.